# best to get the array from get_stream_content()

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services

I have a string which contain spaces after using code `$content1=stream_get_contents($request->getReport());`
   which returns output

```
Order ID    Order date  Fulfillment Channel Points  Bonus   Message response greater than 24 hours  Late Shipment   Cancellation    Negative Feedback
002-3444-XXXX   10/31/15    Fulfilled by Amazon 100                                 
002-XXXX-XXX7   10/31/15    Fulfilled by Amazon 100
```

I want to convert the above string into array like the following below

```
  $array['Order ID']=002-3444-XXXX;
  $array['Order date']=10/31/15;
  $array['Fulfillment Channel']=Fulfilled by Amazon;
  $array['Points']=100;
  $array['Bonus']='';..... so on
```

please suggest me a possible way to convert the string into array.

Comment: Do you always only have those 5 params ?

Comment: no we might have Message, response, greater than 24 hours, Late Shipment ,Cancellation ,Negative Feedback if there will be any value for them

Comment: Well I could write you a function for that but that would be very specific :/ so I dont know if it would be really that useful

Comment: let me know your function may be that would help me..and i'll modify it acc. to my requirement

Comment: @Nirnae can you share your function to convert stream content into array?

Comment: Well it's a little harder than what I expected and I have a lot of work to do by my side, so I'll just give you the beginning of my code but dont just copy and paste it since it'll probably wont be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, as I said, it's a bit messy and i'm not very good with regex, so be careful when using it .

```
<?php
//Our Response from AMAZON
$string = 'Order ID    Order date  Fulfillment Channel Points  Bonus   Message response greater than 24 hours  Late Shipment   Cancellation    Negative Feedback002-3444-XXXX   10/31/15    Fulfilled by Amazon 100   002-XXXX-XXX7   10/31/15    Fulfilled by Amazon 100';

//Since we already know all the headers, we dont need to keep them into the response
$noHeaderStr = substr($string, strpos($string,'Feedback')+8);

//Split the remaining data into an arry
$arrayData = explode('   ', $noHeaderStr);

//Prepare Regex for data verification :
$patternID = '/^([0-9]{3})-(.*){4}-(.*){4}$/';
$patternDate= '/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})$/';
$patternBonus = '/^[0-9]{3}$/';

//index for every order
$i = 0;

//Now we test every data
foreach ($arrayData as $data){
     if (preg_match($patternID, $data)) {
        //if we find an ID, that mean a new order so a new array too
        $newArray[$i] = array();
        $newArray[$i]['OrderID'] = $data;   

     }elseif(preg_match($patternDate, $data)) {
        $newArray[$i]['Order date '] = $data;
        var_dump($newArray[$i]);
        $i++;
     }


     //THIS PART IS MESSY
     /*elseif($data == 'Fulfilled by Amazon 100'){
        $newArray[$i]['Fulfillment Channel Points'] = $data;
        var_dump($newArray[$i]);
        $i++;
     }elseif(preg_match($patternBonus, $data)){
        $newArray[$i]['Bonus'] = $data;
     }*/
}

?>
```

This incrementation on the $i should be on the last if matched.

From what I've given to you for now you should receive something like this from the var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
  'OrderID' => string '002-3444-XXXX' (length=13)
  'Order date ' => string '10/31/15' (length=8)
array (size=2)
  'OrderID' => string '002-XXXX-XXX7' (length=13)
  'Order date ' => string '10/31/15' (length=8)
```